# Android Facebook Like Button not appearing properly

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, facebook-like

this may sound trivial but I am currently having difficulty in the display of the LikeButton. It does not look as intended.

It is supposed to look like this. 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/20645/978150/Pm1GbfbVvhpmjVU/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-24%20at%2010.25.15%20AM.png

Instead it looks like the following:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/20645/978150/JEuU1CEq3Dvmzjj/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-24%20at%2010.27.56%20AM.png

Notice the extra long blue space being stretched and "Like" text being extremely small in the second pic.

Here is the code for the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutFacebookLike"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textFacebookIncentiveText"
        style="@style/Huge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="48dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_facebook_incentive_default"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutFacebookLikeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#40000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnContinue"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="32dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/btn_continue"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            <com.facebook.widget.LikeView
                android:id="@+id/likeView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_margin="64dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The code in the activity that I am using is as follows:

```
LikeView mLikeButton = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.likeView1);
mLikeButton.setObjectId("121083561691");
mLikeButton.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);
mLikeButton.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
mLikeButton.setHorizontalAlignment(LikeView.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
mLikeButton.setForegroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Please let me know how I can correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue arises when you have some themes and styling already set for the activity which interferes with the design of the LikeButton. If you set the default values, the Like Button appears normal.